# Should I use the <figure> and <figcaption> tags for an employees page?

Tags: html

I sort of get what `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` are used for. If I have an employees page, would it be semantically correct to use it for employee images?

Seems like I have two options:

```
  <figure>   
    <img src="bill_carpenter.png">   
    <figcaption>Bill Carpenter</figcaption> 
  </figure>
```

or

```
<div>
  <img src="bill_carpenter.png">
  <p>Bill Carpenter</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is Bill just an illustrative side panel to a main body of text/information? Or is he the *main* information?

Comment: @deceze He would be one of the many employees on the page. It would look like a standard "Our Team" page with a bunch of employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [defining standard says](https://developers.whatwg.org/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element):

> A `figure` element's contents are part of the surrounding flow. If the purpose of the page is to display the figure, for example a photograph on an image sharing site, the `figure` and `figcaption` elements can be used to explicitly provide a caption for that figure.

So, yes, if the purpose is to display a captioned photo of Bill, using `<figure>` is entirely appropriate.